# How can I tell when UIImagePickerController is done switching cameras?

Tags: ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am encountering an issue where if I try to take a picture with `UIImagePickerController` immediately after switching the `cameraDevice` from back to front camera or vice versa I get an error:

```
UIImagePickerController: ignoring request to take picture; camera is changing modes.
```

I have tried subscribing to the `AVCaptureSession*` events from `NSNotificationCenter`, but none of the capture session ready notifications are fired when the camera device changes. Is there a way to determine that the camera is ready again after switching cameras in `UIImagePickerController`?

Comment: I have been able to work around this by disabling the shutter button when I switch camera devices and re-enabling it after a 0.5 second delay. This seems really hacky though, so I'd prefer a more robust way of handling the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the code below:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                 selector:@selector(cameraIsReady:)
                                     AVCaptureSessionInterruptionEndedNotification object:nil];
```

You would use this to kick off the code you want once the cameras are ready.

If you post your code, I can come back and edit in further help for you.

Comment: Yes, I am already listening for the `AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification` and `AVCaptureSessionDidStopRunningNotification`. They do not fire when you change `UIImagePickerController`'s `cameraDevice` property. At least, not on my iPad running iOS 8.1.

Comment: Actually, I'm already listening for all of the AVCaptureSession notifications: AVCaptureSessionRuntimeErrorNotification, AVCaptureSessionDidStartRunningNotification, AVCaptureSessionDidStopRunningNotification, AVCaptureSessionWasInterruptedNotification, and AVCaptureSessionInterruptionEndedNotification. None of them are fired when I change the cameraDevice property.